# WatchKit - Access Data From iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, watchkit

I am working on a prototype app that tracks buses for our town. One of the features of the app involves the user being able to "star" buses so that they can be displayed on a list of favorites for easy access. I currently user NSUserDefaults to store the list of favorites on the iOS app. This works fine for the iOS side of the app, however I am now at the point where I would like to add an Apple Watch extension that can also display favorites that the user has selected. Is there any way for the watch extension to access the NSUserDefaults saved on the phone? If not, what is the best way to store the favorites in the iOS app so that they can be accessed by the watch extension?

Answer (score 1):

Hi in your case you've to use app groups enable app group  for iOS as well as WatchKit extension and share your NSUserDefaults

Answer (score -1):

You can use firebase as a database here and connect both iOS and WatchOS to firebase.

Comment: There has to be a simpler way to get such a small amount of data from the iPhone

Comment: May be you can use the Multipeer connectivity Framework but for that  to work the iPhone and iWatch must be on the same network.